# firing load event when href of an image tag is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an image tag in my HTML code like this:

```
<image
    transform="scale(1, 1)"
    id="uniqueDomId-301"
    data-original-image="01"
    x="-6"
    y="-6"
    opacity="1"
    xlink:href="https://www.armytimes.com/resizer/DSRTzWuazXDDnMGKhI_WjpsejqE=/1200x0/filters:quality(100)/arc-anglerfish-arc2-prod-mco.s3.amazonaws.com/public/I7BT6CWECJDIVDKFA25OQBFQ7M.jpg"
    height="756"
    width="1445"
    data-accepts="events"
    data-reactid=".0.0.3.2.0.1.0:$_player=15g5VJPvQEXE=16hc3eOukv2x.0.3:$c249.1:$c256.$slideobject299.$0.$0.$0"
></image>
```

What if we want to check the image is fully loaded by its `xlink:href` attribute?

I have used something like this without success:

```js
coverLoaded(); 
function coverLoaded(){

    const coverSelector = $('#uniqueDomId-301')[0].getAttribute("xlink:href");

    console.log(coverSelector); // I can select the href this way

    coverSelector.on("load", function() {
       console.log('image is fully loaded!');
    }); 

}
```

```html
<image
    transform="scale(1, 1)"
    id="uniqueDomId-301"
    data-original-image="01"
    x="-6"
    y="-6"
    opacity="1"
    xlink:href="https://www.armytimes.com/resizer/DSRTzWuazXDDnMGKhI_WjpsejqE=/1200x0/filters:quality(100)/arc-anglerfish-arc2-prod-mco.s3.amazonaws.com/public/I7BT6CWECJDIVDKFA25OQBFQ7M.jpg"
    height="756"
    width="1445"
    data-accepts="events"
    data-reactid=".0.0.3.2.0.1.0:$_player=15g5VJPvQEXE=16hc3eOukv2x.0.3:$c249.1:$c256.$slideobject299.$0.$0.$0"
></image>
```

Somehow we want to fire the event if this image is loaded:

```
xlink:href="https://www.armytimes.com/resizer/DSRTzWuazXDDnMGKhI_WjpsejqE=/1200x0/filters:quality(100)/arc-anglerfish-arc2-prod-mco.s3.amazonaws.com/public/I7BT6CWECJDIVDKFA25OQBFQ7M.jpg"
```

Comment: `<image></image>` is not a valid html element so it is probably from some other framework and quite possibly has it's own `onLoad`. Where does it come from?

Comment: Also looking at the issue incorrectly. You want a listener on the rendered element, not for a url string.

Comment: `const coverSelector = $('#uniqueDomId-301')[0].getAttribute("xlink:href");` It seems like you are combing jQuery and vanilla javascript. Could that be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

First of all "image" is not proper html. So you probably need to use "img".

You could use an eventListener on any element. There is an event called "load". You also have to make sure the javascript which adds the eventlistener is loaded before the image is loaded. You could do this by placing the script in the head.

How to use the load event:

```
element.addEventListener("load", () => {
    //will be executed after element is loaded.
});
```

You could also use this event execute after the entire page has loaded, like this:

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    //will be executed after page is loaded.
});
```